# Mock of JaegerTracer giving Null Pointer Exception in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5, jaeger

Can anyone please help me to fix the Null Pointer Exception I am facing while trying to write Junit for a service having JaergerTracer in Springboot.
I have a Spring Boot service which user Jaeger for spans..the service is working fine but the Junit is giving NPE as the mocked JaegerTracer is giving null..

I have used JUnit5 and SpringBoot 2.7.6.

Requesting to please check and suggest..

**Service**

```
@Service
public class RestClientHeroMovieService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RestClientService restClientService;

    @Autowired
    private StatisticsConfig statisticsConfig;

    @Autowired
    private JaegerTracer jaegerTracer;

    @Value("${test.value}")
    private String testValue;

    public HeroMovie getHeroMovieDetails(String heroName) throws URISyntaxException {

        Span span = jaegerTracer.buildSpan("getHeroMovieDetails").start(); //giving NPE as jaegerTracer is null

        Span spanHeroMovie = jaegerTracer.buildSpan("spanHeroMovie").asChildOf(span).start();
        String endpoint = "http://localhost:9050/orders/v1/getHeroDetails/"+heroName;

        HeroMovie heroMovie = restTemplate.getForObject(endpoint,HeroMovie.class);
        spanHeroMovie.finish();

        endpoint = "http://localhost:9050/orders/v1/getMoviesOfHero/"+heroName;
        URI uri = new URI(endpoint);

        Span spanListMovie = jaegerTracer.buildSpan("spanListMovie").asChildOf(span).start();
        List<Movie> listMovie = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Movie>>(){}).getBody();
        heroMovie.setMovies(listMovie);
        spanListMovie.finish();

        heroMovie.setPlatforms(statisticsConfig.getPlatforms());
        heroMovie.setBrowsers(statisticsConfig.getBrowsers());
        heroMovie.setSystems(statisticsConfig.getSystems());

        heroMovie.setSomeTestValue(testValue);

        heroMovie.setPet(getPet(heroMovie.getHeroName()));

        restClientService.clearAllCache();

        span.finish();
        return heroMovie;

    }
```

**JUnit**

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})  
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class})  
@SpringBootTest(classes = {RestClientHeroMovieServiceTest.class, StatisticsConfig.class}) 
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {StatisticsConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class RestClientHeroMovieServiceTest {

    private final String testValue = "aaa";

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private RestClientHeroMovieService restClientHeroMovieService;
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Mock
    private RestClientService restClientService;

    @Mock
    private StatisticsConfig statisticsConfig;

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private JaegerTracer jaegerTracer;

    @BeforeEach
    public void init() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(restClientHeroMovieService, "testValue", testValue);
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void testGetHeroMovieDetails() {

        HeroMovie heroMovie = getHeroMovie();

        restClientHeroMovieService.setJaegerTracer(jaegerTracer);
        Mockito.when(jaegerTracer.buildSpan(Mockito.anyString()).start())
                .thenReturn(Mockito.mock(JaegerSpan.class));

        Mockito.doReturn(heroMovie)
                .when(restTemplate)
                .getForObject(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any());

        List<Movie> listMovie = getListMovie();
        ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> responseEntityListMovie = ResponseEntity.ok(listMovie);

        Mockito.doReturn(responseEntityListMovie)
                .when(restTemplate)
                .exchange(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(ParameterizedTypeReference.class));

        Mockito.doNothing()
                .when(restClientService)
                .clearAllCache();

        Assertions.assertTrue(heroMovie.getHeroName().equalsIgnoreCase("test") && heroMovie.getMovies().get(0).getMovieName().equalsIgnoreCase("TestM") && heroMovie.getSomeTestValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testValue));

    }
```

Comment: a) Don't mix Mockito-tests with Spring tests b) `JaegerTracer` is a _class_, not an interface: `when` will call the real method and `anyString()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You should depend on abstractions if possible and not on concrete classes. [`JaegerTracer`](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/blob/master/jaeger-core/src/main/java/io/jaegertracing/internal/JaegerTracer.java) is a class which implements the [`io.opentracing.Tracer`](https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-java/blob/master/opentracing-api/src/main/java/io/opentracing/Tracer.java) interface. Your class should autowire a `Tracer` bean instead.

Mockito still has to follow the rules of the JVM and that means that a statement such as:

```
Mockito.when(jaegerTracer.buildSpan(Mockito.anyString()).start())
        .thenReturn(Mockito.mock(JaegerSpan.class));
```

*must* still call `buildSpan` *and* `start` before the `when` method can be entered (arguments in Java are eagerly evaluated).

Finally, don't mix Mockito tests with Spring tests; their annotations don't mix well and this is most likely the case for why the autowired field is null. Decide on one approach and use one only: either have Spring register beans (and mock beans; defined with `@MockBean`) in the application context and autowire those, or use Mockito to create mock instances and inject those (with `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but is a better approach:

- Jaeger SDKs are deprecated, it's better to use OpenTelemetry
- If you must use Jaeger, use OpenTracing API not Jaeger class
- Your tests don't seem to validate anything about traces, so you don't even need a real Tracer, the OpenTracing by default is installed with noop tracer
- if you do want to validate spans, rather than mocking the tracer you can instantiate a real tracer with in-memory reporter/exporter (exists in both Jaeger and OTEL SDKs), and then interrogate the exporter about which spans were captured